# How can I link other maven pom?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to use mvn install, but of course I get error (The POM for projectA:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available)

How can I link pom for it into this command?

Comment: add more info so the community can help you: your pom.xml, and the path from which you try to run the command....

Answer (score 0):

Maven resolves POMs and other artifacts through the local repository and the repositories given in the `settings.xml` in your `.m2` directory. You do not need to "link" POMs explicitly.